# Is Android canvas.drawBitmap documentation wrong?

Tags: android, android-maps

Is the Android documentation for [canvas.drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) wrong? It says:

> public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)
>
> Draw the specified bitmap, with its top/left corner at (x,y), using the specified paint, transformed by the current matrix.

Well, x and y don’t seem to be floats, they’re ints; is that correct?
Say I want to overlay the bitmap (which is the size of the available screen, and is bound to a canvas of  the same) over the whole available screen. It seems sensible I would:
`canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);`
doesn’t it?
But that doesn’t work. What does seem to work is:
`canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 2000000, 1000000, mPaint)`.
Now that statement seems to me to tell the bitmap that it should draw itself a huge distance
Outside the screen! What am I missing here?

Comment: Android documentation is correct, (0,0) is the top left corner of the screen. Can you edit your question with your codes.

Comment: "transformed by the current matrix.", have you check to make sure do not have some translations in your canvas matrix?

Answer (score 1):

In this method `x` and `y` are floats, not ints. But like mentioned in the documentation, the `x` and `y` coordinates of the bitmaps will be affected by the matrix currently set on the `Canvas`. In the case of a `ScrollView` for instance, the matrix could very well contain a very large translation.

What this means is that the coordinates `0, 0` will draw the bitmap at the current origin of the `Canvas`. That origin is defined by the matrix you can query with `getMatrix()`.

Comment: I have changed the code to: <code>canvas.drawBitmap(mCalculationBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, mPaint);</code>. Overall behavior has improved. Still a ways to  go. I'll get back. Thank you.

Comment: @Romain Guy hi sir, how to scale the image more than its original size using Matrix transformation...